# insufficient memory for this operation en ClientDataset

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, delphi-rio

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta con Delphi Rio 10.3.3 a mi base de datos que me devuelve aprox. 180.000 registros con 13 columnas.

Como cliente de conexión estoy utilizando UniDAC 8.1.2

al intentar realizar la consulta me salta este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya busque en varios foros al respecto y solo me aparece algo de configurar el SHAREDMEMSIZE en el BDE administrator, el cual al parecer la versión de Delphi que estoy usando no posee.

Si alguien me podria dar una mano me ayudaría bastante.

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Te puede ayudar a encontrar una respuesta oportuna revisar: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Es importante incluir la parte del código que te presenta los problemas, para que quien pueda responder lo pueda reproducir.

Comment: 180,000 filas parece algo que el CDS debiera ser capaz de manejar sin problema y hay casos donde puede ser legítimo cargar esta cantidad de información (no si es para consumo humano, claro). Una posible solución es compilar tu aplicación para win64, esto ampliará el espacio de memoria disponible a una cantidad muuuy superior a la memoria instalada, desde los típicos 2Gb de memoria de un proceso de 32 bits.

Comment: @jachguate por ahora con eso parece hacerse solucionado el problema.
Muchas Gracias!!

Comment: @Lucas, lo publiqué como respuesta, entonces. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

180K filas parece algo que el ClientDataSet debiera ser capaz de manejar sin problema.

Debes considerar, por supuesto, que si estas cargando esa cantidad de información para consumo humano, es algo muy cuestionable, pues una persona difícilmente puede procesar más de un puñado de registros a la vez.

Dicho esto, hay casos donde puede ser legítimo cargar esta cantidad de información, ya sea para realizar algún proceso, cálculo, mantener un caché en caliente, etc.

Si este fuera el caso, una posible solución es compilar tu aplicación para la plataforma **win64**, ya que esto ampliará el espacio de memoria disponible a una cantidad muy superior a la memoria instalada, mientras que en **win32** lo típicos es tener direccionable solo 2Gb de memoria (hasta 3 si haces ajustes a tu ejecutable).

Answer (score 2):

El error que te está dando es claro. *La operación que estás intentando realizar requiere demasiada memoria*.

Sinceramente, creo que la solución no es aumentar la memoria, sino modificar el proceso que estás realizando para que no la consuma. Si la aumentas ahora y dentro de un tiempo en lugar de ser 180.000 registros pueden ser 240.000 volverás a tener el mismo  problema.

**Realizar una consulta que devuelva 180.000 registros**, no parece ni lógico ni adecuado. Tampoco explicas qué hace ese proceso, así que tal vez deberías centrar la consulta en eso y dar más datos de esa operación.

Creo (sin tener más datos) que deberías centrarte en modificar ese proceso.

Comment: Entiendo.
En todo caso si ahora mismo mi unica opcion es aumentar la memoria hasta que pueda modificar el proceso, se podria?